# Editing autocomplete in XCode 4. Adding a ]; to autocomplete +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In XCode 4, when you use this code

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
```

the autocomplete kicks in and you get this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:First Object, nil
```

Can I somehow edit the source material to have XCode insert a square bracket and semicolon after nil so I don't have to navigate to the end of the line when I'm using these methods?

Other questions pertaining to the formatting of autocomplete seem to focus on where the +/- goes and which line the first curly brace appears.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your own code snippets.  Here's a link I found particularly useful to learning how to create these: http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/xcode_4_code_snippets